# Python Unit Testing a mocked function calls the original function and fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have the following scripts:

notification.py:

```
def get_notification(some_data):
    
    data = details["type"]
    notification = {"config1":data, "config2":some_data}
    return notification
```

test_notification.py:

```
from notification import get_notification
import pytest

def test_get_notifications(mocker):
    mocker.patch('notification.get_notification',return_value="SUCCESS")
    result = get_notification(some_data)
    assert result == "SUCCESS"
```

Instead of returning "SUCCESS" by the mocked function, the original function is getting called.

I tried using  @patch.object which also resulted in calling of the original function.

```
@patch.object(notification, 'get_notification')

def test_get_notifications(get_notification_mock):
    get_notification_mock.return_value="SUCCESS"
    result = get_notification(some_data)
    assert result == "SUCCESS"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because once you have imported `get_notification`, it does not "belong" to the `notification` module but to the `test_notification` module.
You have to modify your patch to point to the test_notification:

```py
mocker.patch("test_notification.get_notification", return_value="SUCCESS")
# or
mocker.patch(__name__ + ".get_notification", return_value="SUCCESS")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example(`debug.py`):

```
from unittest.mock import patch


def get_notification():
    return 'failed'


def test_get_notifications():
    with patch(
        # change 'debug' to your module name('notification')...
        'debug.get_notification',
        return_value='SUCCESS'
    ):
        assert get_notification() == "SUCCESS"
```

Run `pytest debug.py`:

```
===================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: PATH TO PROJECT...
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                               

debug.py .                                                                                                                                               [100%]

====================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s =======================================================================
```